# Database Snapshots

Tags: ms-access

I've been asked randomly by the director of the organisation I work for to create weekly Database SNAPSHOTS on our 10 or so databases. However, they are all on Access.

What does he mean by this? Any help at all would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is he is using snapshot to mean a file copy of the Access database.  But I suggest you don't rely on any of us to guess.  Ask him instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume he means to create weekly backups of your databases and if this is the case, just duplicate the files once per week and add the date into the file name so you know when it's from.  I'd ask for verification first though as this could mean many things.